# Hackerrank's Minimum Average Waiting Time

Tags: java, algorithm

Link to challenge can be found [**here**](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-average-waiting-time)

> **Problem Statement**
>
> Tieu owns a pizza restaurant and he manages it in his own way. While
>   in a normal restaurant, a customer is served by following the
>   first-come, first-served rule, Tieu simply minimizes the average
>   waiting time of his customers. So he gets to decide who is served
>   first, regardless of how sooner or later a person comes.
>
> Different kinds of pizzas take different amounts of time to cook.
>   Also, once he starts cooking a pizza, he cannot cook another pizza
>   until the first pizza is completely cooked. Let's say we have three
>   customers who come at time t=0, t=1, & t=2 respectively, and the time
>   needed to cook their pizzas is 3, 9, & 6 respectively. If Tieu applies
>   first-come, first-served rule, then the waiting time of three
>   customers is 3, 11, & 16 respectively. The average waiting time in
>   this case is (3 + 11 + 16) / 3 = 10. This is not an optimized
>   solution. After serving the first customer at time t=3, Tieu can
>   choose to serve the third customer. In that case, the waiting time
>   will be 3, 7, & 17 respectively. Hence the average waiting time is (3
>   + 7 + 17) / 3 = 9.
>
> Help Tieu achieve the minimum average waiting time. For the sake of
>   simplicity, just find the integer part of the minimum average waiting
>   time.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer N, which is the number of
>   customers. In the next N lines, the ith line contains two space
>   separated numbers Ti and Li. Ti is the time when ith customer order a
>   pizza, and Li is the time required to cook that pizza. Output Format
>
> Display the integer part of the minimum average waiting time.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
>
> 0 ≤ Ti ≤ 10^9
>
> 1 ≤ Li ≤ 10^9
>
> **Note**
>
> The waiting time is calculated as the difference between the time a
>   customer orders pizza (the time at which they enter the shop) and the
>   time she is served.
>
> Cook does not know about the future orders.

I've been at this for several hours.

I'm pretty sure my problems has to do with the way I increment the total Wait time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();

        MinimumAverageWaitingTime mawt = new MinimumAverageWaitingTime();

        while(n-- > 0) mawt.insert(s.nextLong(), s.nextLong());
        System.out.print(mawt.calculateAverageWaitingTime());
    }
}

class MinimumAverageWaitingTime {
    private PriorityQueue<e_time_p_time> incomingOrders = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new Comparator<e_time_p_time>(){
        //Order by the customerWaitTime ASC
        @Override public int compare(e_time_p_time w, e_time_p_time w1) {
            return (int) (w.entryTime - w1.entryTime);
        }
    });
    private PriorityQueue<e_time_p_time> awaitingOrders = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new Comparator<e_time_p_time>(){
        //Order by the difference between entrytime and pizzaCookTime ASC
        @Override public int compare(e_time_p_time w, e_time_p_time w1) {
            return (int) (Math.abs(w.entryTime - w.pizzaCookTime) - Math.abs(w1.entryTime - w1.pizzaCookTime));
        }
    });

    private long total = 0l;

    public void insert(long customerWaitTime, long pizzaCookTime) {                
        incomingOrders.add(new e_time_p_time(customerWaitTime, pizzaCookTime));
    }

    public long calculateAverageWaitingTime() {
        int size = incomingOrders.size();

        e_time_p_time currentOrder = null;
        e_time_p_time laterOrders = null;

        while(incomingOrders.size() > 0) {
            //Start by getting the customer that has the earliest arrival time (the queue is sorted that way)
            currentOrder = incomingOrders.remove();

            //Calculate it's waiting time. 
            total += currentOrder.entryTime + currentOrder.pizzaCookTime;

            do {
                /*Move all the customers that entered the shop while the current pizza is in the oven
                  to the awaitingOrders orders queue*/
                laterOrders = incomingOrders.remove(); 
                awaitingOrders.add(laterOrders);
            } while (currentOrder.pizzaCookTime >= laterOrders.entryTime && incomingOrders.size() > 0);

            //Go through awaitingOrders queue and calculate waiting time for the remaining orders
            //(The queue is sorted as the difference between entrytime and pizzaCookTime ASC)
            while(awaitingOrders.size() > 0) {
                e_time_p_time shortestOrder = awaitingOrders.remove();
                long waitTimeBeforeCooking = Math.abs((shortestOrder.entryTime + shortestOrder.pizzaCookTime) - currentOrder.entryTime);
                total += waitTimeBeforeCooking;
            }
        }

        //It's supposed to be the average time, but first I need the total to be correct, and right now, it's not...
        System.out.println("\nTotal waiting time: ");
        return total;
    }

    private static class e_time_p_time {
        private long entryTime;
        private long pizzaCookTime;

        e_time_p_time(long entryTime, long pizzaCookTime) {
            this.entryTime = entryTime;
            this.pizzaCookTime = pizzaCookTime;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
     do {
            /*Move all the customers that entered the shop while the current pizza is in the oven
              to the awaitingOrders orders queue*/
            laterOrders = incomingOrders.remove(); 
            awaitingOrders.add(laterOrders);
        } while (currentOrder.pizzaCookTime >= laterOrders.entryTime && incomingOrders.size() > 0);
```

A couple of things seem wrong here:

1. You always add at least one item to awaitingOrders - but what if no-one enters the shop while the current pizza is in the oven?  (e.g. for the last pizza)
2. You compare the pizzaCookTime - e.g. ten minutes, with the entryTime, e.g. 4pm.  This doesn't seem right - shouldn't you compare the time that the pizza is completed with the entryTime?

Comment: Sorry Peter, I don't know what happened, but I swore I saw that you had asked the question. So that's why I thought was a continuation.

Comment: "For example, what if I the first arriving customer takes 5 hours to cook their pizza, followed by a hundred customers that take 1 minute. Won't your algorithm force everyone to wait for 5 hours?" Well - yes. Because the challenge states that the cook does not know about feature orders. Unless I'm misunderstanding of course.

Comment: I'd missed that line - yes I think you are quite right - I'll delete that part

Comment: But I agree with your first suggestion. The second am I bit unsure of. Im interested in finding the customers that enters the store while the current pizza is in the oven. I won't find that out by comparing the time that the pizza is completed with the entryTime?

Comment: I believe pizzaCookTime is how long it takes to cook - i.e. the difference between the pizza completed time and the pizza start time.